# Can not pass variable from method to the test - protractor

Tags: typescript, promise, protractor

I am writing a test checking for the amount of gold I have. I am using typescrypt and protractor.

I have a method GetAmoutOfChips:

```
public static GetAmountOfChips(): PromiseLike<any> {
    let chips: number = 1;
    NavigateTo.myProfile();
    browser.sleep(900);
    let promise = MyProfile.Basic.chipsAmount.getText().then((chipAmount) => {
        chips = parseInt(chipAmount);
        console.log("+++++++++++1" + chips);
    });
    MyProfile.Basic.close.click();
    console.log("+++++++++++2" + chips);
    return promise;
}
```

I would like to use it in a test. So I am doing the following:

```
Actions.Basic.GetAmountOfChips().then((chipAmount: number) => {
            chipsBalance = chipAmount;
            console.log("+++++REAL" + chipsBalance);
        });
```

console.log#1 returns the value i want to use. console.log#2 returns undentified. So I can not pass the variable to the test. What do i do to pass the variable from the method to the test?

Comment: You need to make the test asynchronous.

Comment: Any help how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do everything inside the **then**. You can also return the value there to create another promise.

```js
public static GetAmountOfChips(): PromiseLike<any> {
    NavigateTo.myProfile();
    browser.sleep(900);
    let promise = MyProfile.Basic.chipsAmount.getText().then((chipAmount) => {
        // this is executed asynchronously
        MyProfile.Basic.close.click();

        // return a value to create another promise        
        return parseInt(chipAmount);

    });

    return promise;
}
```

Promises can be quite confusing, you can find out more [here](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html).

In your test you must also do the checks in the **then** function.

```js
Actions.Basic.GetAmountOfChips().then((chipAmount: number) => {
  // test here not outside 
  expect(chipAmount).toBe(10);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm! I had problems understanding this for the last 2 days. <3

Comment: @Bakanomercy the way you can think about it is that anything that's in a then function can happen at any point in time, that means no code should rely on it happening at a set point in time.